# copy constructor is triggered but how?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class someClass{
    char * data;
public:
    someClass(const char * s){
        data = new char[strlen(s)+1];
        strcpy(data,s);
        cout << "constructing.."<<endl;
    }

    someClass(const someClass &o){
        data = new char[strlen(o.data)];
        strcpy(data,o.data);
        cout << "copy construction" << endl;
    }

    ~someClass(){delete [] data; cout << "destructing..." << endl;}
    char * getValue(){return data;}
};

void showValue(someClass o){
    char * s;
    s = o.getValue();
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    someClass str("Hello"), ptr("world");
    showValue(str);
    showValue(ptr);
}
```

and the output is:

```
constructing..
constructing..
copy construction
Hello
destructing...
copy construction
world
destructing...
destructing...
destructing...
```

1. Now first two 'constructing..' are triggered as soon as we create the object in main() on line 1.
2. showValue(*str*) runs and it triggers copy constructor for the word 'hello'. **How?** After creating and temporary object, it destructs itself when it's out of function.
3. showValue(*ptr*) runs and it triggers copy constructor for the word 'world'. **How?** After creating and temporary object, it destructs itself when it's out of function.
4. Lastly, in reverse order our str and ptr objects are being destroyed.

Why has copy ctor run? I didn't send a someClass object to a someClass object. Can you explain me the situation?

Comment: Tangential, but worth reading if you are making copy constructors: [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making copies when you call

```
void showValue(someClass o)
```

If you want to avoid copies, pass by reference

```
void showValue(someClass const& o)
```

In the first case `o` is a function-local copy of your `someClass` argument, that is destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: Doesn't it create a temporary object when we pass the object to a function as an argument?

Comment: It depends on the signature of your function. In the answer I posted, the first method will create a copy, the second method will not.

Answer (score 2):

```
void showValue(someClass o){
    char * s;
    s = o.getValue();
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

this part of your cade invokes the copy constructor of `someClass`.
If you want to get rid of it, you can change your class to:

```
 void showValue(const someClass & o){
        char * s;
        s = o.getValue();
        cout << s << endl;
    }
```

and change GetValue to:

```
 char * getValue() const {return data;}
```

This is called passing by const-reference, as opposed to passing by value (what you were doing). When you pass by value, the function invokes the copy constructor of the class called.

The change on `getValue()` suggested is because the compiler wants to be sure that the call to `getValue` inside of `showValue` will not modify the member objects of the const element `const someClass & o`.